# Mockito - How to spy on Invocation argument in doAnswer

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

This is my first day writing Unit tests using Mockito and I might have started with a complex exercise.

Below is my class structure and I am writing tests for Class2.targetMethod(). Class1 static method modifies passed in object instead of returning any results.

```
class Class1 {
    static void dbquery(OutParam out) {
        // Complex code to fill in db results in OutParam object
    }
}

class Class2 {
    void targetMethod() {
        OutParam p1 = new OutParam1();
        Class1.dbquery(p1);
        ResultSet rs = p1.getCursor();
        ...
    }
}
```

Below is my setup for the tests:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class Class2Test {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class1.class);

        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Exception {
                OutParam result = (OutParam)invocation.getArguments()[1];
                OutParam spy = spy(result);
                ResultSet mockResult = mock(ResultSet.class);
                doReturn(mockResult).when(spy.getCursor());
                when(mockResult.getString("some_id")).thenReturn("first_id","second_id");
                when(mockResult.getString("name")).thenReturn("name1","name2");

                return null;
            }
        }).when(Class1.class, "dbquery", any());
    }
}
```

However the tests fail with exception below - mainly due to "doReturn" line.

Any suggestions on this problem or if my approach is completely wrong.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for:

```
doReturn(mockResult).when(spy.getCursor());
```

should be:

```
doReturn(mockResult).when(spy).getCursor();
```

By calling `when` with only the `spy`, and not `spy.getCursor()`, you give Mockito a chance to *temporarily deactivate `getCursor`* so you can stub it without calling the real thing. Though that doesn't seem to be important here, Mockito insists that you keep this pattern for calls to `when` following `doAnswer` (etc).

Comment: Thanks Jeff. This actually solved the exception issue. However, it seems like "spy" only applies to the reference in doAnswer code. I can see the spy if I set a breakpoint. But original reference in targetMethod() does not seem to be spied on. So it continues to call real method. How can I force the original reference/object to be spied on? Thanks again!

Comment: `spy` creates a _duplicate_ of the passed-in object, with overridable methods. It's no remote control: In order for your spy to take effect, you're going to need to insert it back into your object so your system under test calls the spy instead. It may be easier to install the spy on object creation (in a `@Before` method or at the beginning of your test) and only _stub_ it later.

Comment: Thanks very much, Jeff, for your help. I modified the target class itself to set the spy object in place of original object from the test.